# Chrome mobile app URL redirection issue

Tags: php, google-chrome, yii, yii2, google-chrome-app

I have a domain https://billfree.in
the code of which is implemented in yii2. I have another domain [blfr.in](http://blfr.in) which I use as a short domain to send SMS to the users as blfr.in/r/abc123. Furthermore, I have implemented urlRules which run the redir/index controller when such type of url is requested, with abc123 as an id that goes in the parameter as : `actionIndex($id)`
Also, I have added a 302 redirect on the DNS setting of blfr.in so that it is understood as `billfree.in/r/abc123`
Everything seems to work fine, the user clicks on `blfr.in/r/abc123` and it is redirected to `billfree.in/r/abc123`. From there yii takes care of the request and calls the redir/index function with id as abc123.

Now the problem: when I open `blfr.in/r/abc123` on Chrome mobile app (Firefox works fine here!), the first time I am redirected to `billfree.in/r/abc123` successfully. The next time, if there's another link say `blfr.in/r/xyz123`, chrome app somehow picks the url from cache and the redirected url now becomes `billfree.in/abc123/xyz123`
There is a chaining of these parameters resulting in 404 error. Can someone please explain how I can fix this. Thanks.

**Note that these URLs are intended to be opened by the mobile phone as there's a mobile device checker in place here too. abc123 is a dummy id value and might not work, let me know if you need a working id value for reference**

Comment: Need to see your Controller and View code.

Answer (score 0):

Generate  your  URL  like this :

```
echo  Url::to(['/your-model/youraction-or-anything-else'])."/".$$model->id-or-any-parametter;
```

Comment: use yii\helpers\Url;  put it on the top of your code ,